# How does malloc() know you want to use the block of memory it supplies as an array?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

If `malloc()` returns a pointer to a single block of memory, how can it be used to store multiple values contiguously and allow access to each one using the subscript operator, acting as a pointer to an array?

If I were to try and change the "second element" of an integer by subscripting its address, it would cause undefined behaviour. As `malloc()` returns the pointer to a single block of memory, shouldn't the pointer it returns refer to the entire block, and thus subscripting it should access the garbage value next to it in memory?

Furthermore, the allocated memory can also be used to store a single value, but only up to the size of the type the pointer is cast to, not to that of the allocated block of memory.

Is all this something to do with the type the pointer is cast to after being returned? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: *"Is all this something to do with the type the pointer is cast to after being returned"* - first, you don't need to cast anything. C freely transposes `void*` to `type*` and back. Second, yes, and the food for google-fu is *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I thought "cast" was shorthand for both explicit and implicit type conversion. Anyway, thank you for the search term, I'm checking it out!

Comment: @WhozCraig Okay, I get it now, but I still don't understand why the block can only hold a single value up to the size of the type of pointer? Can you clarify how/why it is segmented like this?

Comment: the simple answer, `malloc()` does NOT know what your program is going to use the allocated heap memory for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding is here:

> As malloc() returns the pointer to a single block of memory, shouldn't the pointer it returns refer to the entire block, and thus subscripting it should access the garbage value next to it in memory?

Indeed if you do `p = malloc(n)` and `p` has type "pointer to some type of size `n`", then `p[1]` is an out-of-bounds array access. However, normally when you do `p = malloc(n)` to allocate an array, the type of `p` is not a pointer to the array (of size `n`), but a pointer to the *first element of* the array. That is, instead of

```
char (*p)[500] = malloc(500);
```

you do:

```
char *p = malloc(500);
```

and in this case `p[1]` is perfectly valid. Note that with the first, unusual, form, you could still do `(*p)[1]` or `p[0][1]` and have it be valid.

Answer (score 0):

But be careful, if you use malloc several times it will return memory allocated in different parts of heap. So you can't move around from one array to another.